# Unable to cast ListView to ListViewItem

Tags: vb.net, listview

This one seems nonsensical to me. I'm getting an InvalidCastException with "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' on the starred line below:

```
Public Class FormX
    Public DT As DataTable
    Public trnBool As Boolean
    Dim lV As ListView
    Dim trnLVI As ListViewItem
    Dim PClviList As List(Of ListViewItem)

    Private Sub FormAllocationsLeaveTypes_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        lV = ListViewLT

        lV.Items.Clear()
        lV.Groups.Clear()

        Dim lvGS As ListViewGroup, lvGP As ListViewGroup, lvI As ListViewItem

        lvGS = New ListViewGroup("Shift Type", HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        lvGP = New ListViewGroup("PC Types", HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        lV.Groups.AddRange({lvGS, lvGP})

        trnLVI = New ListViewItem("Training Shifts") With {.Checked = trnBool}
        lV.Items.Add(trnLVI).Group = lvGS '*** Exception occurs here

        PClviList = New List(Of ListViewItem)
        For Each LT As DataRow In DT.Rows
            lvI = New ListViewItem(LT("HrsType").ToString) With {.Checked = Not LT("Show").ToString = String.Empty}
            lV.Items.Add(lvI).Group = lvGP
            PClviList.Add(lvI)
        Next LT

    End Sub
End Class
```

The exception makes it look like it's saying that my variable trnLVI is of type ListView. I even checked in the immediate window for trnLVI.GetType.Name and it returned ListViewItem.

I've tried assigning the group before and after, no difference. I've also got virtually identical syntax performing this same action in another form of the same project, using a ListView that I copied to make this one. The only real difference is that this ListView has only 1 column where that one had a few more.

Comment: If I add the ListViewItems directly to the groups instead of the ListView, it doesn't throw an exception, but nothing appears in the ListView except the single column header when the form shows.

Comment: I just ran your code and I got no such exception on that line. There may be something corrupt in your project. I'd suggest trying with a new form.

Comment: That line of  code looks fine to me.

Comment: Damn, just as I feared. Thanks both.

Comment: I've just recovered an old version known to be fine, rebuilt the form clean, added the code back in, and same problem. I even simplified it to only initialise the new ListViewItem, then add it without any parameters. And I double checked on the other form in the project that uses the same type of code and it's fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. You guys aren't going to believe how silly this was. It wasn't corruption at all.

It made no sense even after rebuilding the form and getting the same result. So I decided to publish it and see if it happened on the published version. But the JIT debugger popped up and informed me the issue was happening in an event that I had much further down in the code "lvI_ItemChecked":

```
Private Sub lvI_ItemChecked(lvI As ListViewItem, e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListViewLeaveTypes.ItemChecked

    changesMade = True
    ButtonSave.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

When I first wrote that block, I assumed the listviewitem initiates the trigger, not the listview itself, so I declared the sender as a ListViewItem, when it's actually a ListView.

It all makes a lot more sense now.